# Flexdashboard: dynamically change navbar title

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

How can I dynamically change the navbar title from a R flexdashboard document. For instance I tried the code below to dynamically display when was the flexdashboard last updated.

If possible, I am looking for a solution that doesn't rely on any external call.

```r
---
title: "My title"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    navbar:
      - { title: `r paste0("Last updated at: ", Sys.time())` }
---
```

But it returns an error:

```r
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the `date` statement:

```
---
title: "Test for Stack Exchange"
date: "Last updated at `r format(Sys.time())`"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works fine, but I wish I could do the same for the navbar buttons. This is what I am looking for.